# iterate over pandas dataframe and create another dataframe with repititive records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `act` with columns as `['ids','start-yr','end-yr']`.
I want to create another dataframe `timeline` with columns as `['ids','years']`.
using the `act` df. So if `act` has fields as

```
ids             start-yr end-yr
--------------------------------
'IAs728-ahe83j'    2014    2016
'J8273nbajsu-193h' 2012    2018
```

I want the `timeline` df to be populated like this:

```
ids                years
------------------------
'IAs728-ahe83j'     2014
'IAs728-ahe83j'     2015
'IAs728-ahe83j'     2016
'J8273nbajsu-193h'  2012
'J8273nbajsu-193h'  2013
'J8273nbajsu-193h'  2014
'J8273nbajsu-193h'  2015
'J8273nbajsu-193h'  2016
'J8273nbajsu-193h'  2017
'J8273nbajsu-193h'  2018
```

My attempt so far:

```
timeline = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ids','years'])

cnt = 0
for ix, row in act.iterrows():
    for yr in range(int(row['start-yr']), int(row['end-yr'])+1, 1):
        timeline[cnt, 'ids'] = row['ids']
        timeline[cnt, 'years'] = yr
        cnt += 1
```

But this is a very costly operation, too much time consuming (which is obvious, i know). So what should be the best pythonic approach to populate a pandas df in a situation like this?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `range` for list of tuples and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = [(i, x) for i, a, b in df.values for x in range(a, b + 1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['ids','years'])
print (df)
                  ids  years
0     'IAs728-ahe83j'   2014
1     'IAs728-ahe83j'   2015
2     'IAs728-ahe83j'   2016
3  'J8273nbajsu-193h'   2012
4  'J8273nbajsu-193h'   2013
5  'J8273nbajsu-193h'   2014
6  'J8273nbajsu-193h'   2015
7  'J8273nbajsu-193h'   2016
8  'J8273nbajsu-193h'   2017
9  'J8273nbajsu-193h'   2018
```

If possible multiple columns in `DataFrame` filter them by list:

```
c = ['ids','start-yr','end-yr']
a = [(i, x) for i, a, b in df[c].values for x in range(a, b + 1)]
```

Comment: wow! you're a genius @jezrael . This only 0.38 seconds.
Could you pls explain why this approach took so less computational time. Sorry for the dumb question. I am dumb. again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @AmanSingh - Because `iterrows` is used for loop by Series, and it is really expensive. So pure python solution working very fast.